# C++: strange behaviour with the pointers to std::map

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, stdmap

I need to share some variable (**myMap**) with the inner class. I tried to do it using following approach:

```
class SecondClass {
public:
    std::map< std::string, short > *myMapPtr;
};

class TestClass {
public:
    SecondClass secondClass;
    std::map< std::string, short > myMap;
    TestClass() {
        printf( "consturctor of TextClass\n" );
        secondClass.myMapPtr = &myMap;
    }
    ~TestClass() {
        printf( "desturctor of TextClass\n" );
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector< TestClass > objArr;
    {
        TestClass newObj;
        objArr.push_back( newObj );
    }
    int i = objArr[ 0 ].secondClass.myMapPtr->count( "test" );
}
```

The problem is that I don't have access to **objArr[ 0 ].secondClass.myMapPtr** anymore. You can compile this code and see that it returns an error: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on the line:

```
int i = objArr[ 0 ].secondClass.myMapPtr->count( "test" );
```

What's wrong here? objArr should stores created objects inside it. Why it doesn't work like this?

**UPD 2:**
@rcrmn, thanks. But I don't understand why when I add another element in my std::vector it brokes my previous pointer:

```
std::vector< TestClass > objArr;
{
    TestClass newObj;
    objArr.push_back( newObj );
    objArr[ 0 ].secondClass.myMapPtr = &objArr[ 0 ].myMap;
}
int i1 = objArr[ 0 ].secondClass.myMapPtr->count( "test" );
{
    TestClass newObj;
    objArr.push_back( newObj );
    objArr[ 1 ].secondClass.myMapPtr = &objArr[ 1 ].myMap;
}
int i2 = objArr[ 0 ].secondClass.myMapPtr->count( "test" );
```

the problem is on the last line. But why? I didn't change the first element of objArr why I haven't access to the first element? ("int i2" line).

**UPD 3**
Even if I do something like this:

```
std::vector< TestClass > objArr;
{
    TestClass newObj;
    objArr.push_back( newObj );
}
objArr[ 0 ].secondClass.myMapPtr = &objArr[ 0 ].myMap;
{
    TestClass newObj;
    objArr.push_back( newObj );
}
objArr[ 1 ].secondClass.myMapPtr = &objArr[ 1 ].myMap;
int i = objArr[ 0 ].secondClass.myMapPtr->count( "test" );
```

I also have that error but why... I store a pointer to **&objArr[ 0 ].myMap** after the scope ends and it shouldn't change the address of the element anymore. Where's my fault?

Comment: lol `std::map` but `printf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main class you are creating an object referenced by the name newObj inside an scope. In its constructor, it takes a pointer to its `std::map` and stores it in the inner class.

```
TestClass() {
    printf( "consturctor of TextClass\n" );
    secondClass.myMapPtr = &myMap; // <- the problem
}
```

The problem is that `push_back` copies the object as is, with the inner object's reference to the `std::map` still referencing the old object's map. So, when leaving the scope, the newObj is destroyed and your reference inside is now invalid.

```
{
    TestClass newObj;
    objArr.push_back( newObj );
}
```

Your best option I think it would be to override the copy constructor of the `TestClass` so the inner class references the correct `std::map`.

**Edit:**

The problem is you are looking at it from a java perspective. In C++ you don't have garbage collector, you have scopes. Objects not created in shared memory (using new, for example), like object variables in a method, are created when the program flow enters the scope and are destroyed when it leaves it.

So, if you keep a reference to the map inside the object, when the object is destroyed when you leave the scope delimited by `{}`, that reference will no longer be to a valid memory location.

**Edit 2:**

Well, actually, now that I think on it, it's quite possible that `std::vector` is reallocating your objects when it increases the size of the array. In that case, the references to the map would no longer be valid.

You can verify this behaviour preallocating the array:

```
std::vector< TestClass > objArr;
objArr.reserve(2);
{
    TestClass newObj;
    objArr.push_back( newObj );
}
objArr[ 0 ].secondClass.myMapPtr = &objArr[ 0 ].myMap;
{
    TestClass newObj;
    objArr.push_back( newObj );
}
objArr[ 1 ].secondClass.myMapPtr = &objArr[ 1 ].myMap;
int i = objArr[ 0 ].secondClass.myMapPtr->count( "test" );
```

But you should really use shared memory for this.

Comment: What if I do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410589/c-stdvector-destroys-a-pointer-to-an-object it brokes my pointer again.

Comment: You should not post new questions, but instead add new data to your question to show your updates.

Comment: ok I've added a new part of my question. Could you update your answer?

Comment: _So, if you keep a reference to the map inside the object, when the object is destroyed when you leave the scope delimited by {}, that reference will no longer be to a valid memory location._ -- yeah but in my last code I try to store a pointer to the element of std::vector not to the original object which will be destroyed after ending the scope.

Comment: I've updated my question again. I don't understand why I can't store a pointer to the element of the std::vector. Maybe std::vector regenerates all its values when I do **push_back**?

Comment: It works only when I do: **objArr[ 0 ].secondClass.myMapPtr = &objArr[ 0 ].myMap; objArr[ 1 ].secondClass.myMapPtr = &objArr[ 1 ].myMap;** after adding the last element. So what's wrong with the **push_back**?

Comment: With the "&(objArr[ 0 ].myMap)" the error still stays :( Well it's not a problem I can update all pointers after adding the last element but I just want to know why it brokes previous pointers when I do push_back. I think this is very strange behaviour. Maybe GCC is the root of the problem :)

Comment: It works with the "objArr.reserve(2);". Now I understand its behaviour :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Because vectors store *copies* and you did not abide by the Rule of Three.

Comment: I think, even if copy constructor will be implemented there will be memory leak because of: secondClass.myMapPtr = &myMap;
or some crash depend of implementation.

Comment: @Neska why? It's just a pointer. There's no memory allocated for myMapPtr.